# How to find the force due to fluid pressure over a surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

The question is about sphere like surfaces, like the hemispherical base of a cylinder as shown. [image]

The cylinder is filled with fluid till the given height $h$, and the density of the fluid is $\rho$ and the system is static.I need to find the force due to pressure on the hemispherical portion at the base. I know that the pressure experienced by a ring of thickness, say, $dx$, if the area it contains is parallel to the top of the cylinder, will be equal throughout the ring. And also, the pressure in the hemispherical region changes from $\rho gh$ to $\rho g(h+r)$ (from the disk at the top to the infinitesimal one at the bottom).

(I've tried to find the Force by integrating $PdA$ over each ring, with their radii ranging from $R$ to $0$, and the pressure varying like I mentioned above, but that apparently is not the right way to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the force due to pressure on the hemispherical portion at the base is equal to the weight of the fluid. You can just calculate the volume  of the fluid and multiply by $\rho g$.

Comment: I did try that but apparently it isn't the answer I'm supposed to get!

Comment: @Hritik Narayan: So what answer did you get in this way?

Comment: $\rho g\pi R^2(h+2R/3)$. Is that what you intended me to find?

Comment: @Hritik Narayan: Looks fine to me. Could you give the exact wording of the problem and "the answer you're supposed to get"?

Comment: I've included all the details of the question in what I've typed up. Apparently the answer is $\rho g \pi R^2 (h-R/3)$.

Comment: @Hritik Narayan: It looks like they measure $h$ from the bottom of the hemisphere, not as the height of the cylinder, as you do.

Comment: I did it by measuring $h$ like you said, and I did get the right answer. Thanks a lot.